# Reactjs couldn't render react-plotly graph with data fetched from backend Fastapi server

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, debugging, fastapi

I built an application with frontend using react and I currently changed my server side code from Flask -> FastAPI. There is nothing wrong with the original Flask with ReactJS version, ReactJS fetch data from server and display the graph successfully on the webpage. Below is the flask + ReactJS version code:

## **Server side: FLASK**

```
@app.route("/bar", methods = ['POST'])
@cross_origin(supports_credentials=True)
def bar():
    df = px.data.medals_wide()
    fig3 = px.bar(df, x="nation", y=["gold", "silver", "bronze"], title="Wide-Form Input", width=1000, height=650)
    graphJSON = plotly.io.to_json(fig3, pretty=True)
    return graphJSON
```

## **Reactjs:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Plot from 'react-plotly.js';
import './Bar.css'

function Bar() {

  const [plot, setPlot] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/bar', { 
      method: 'POST', 
      credentials: 'include' 
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {setPlot(data); console.log(plot)});
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="bar">
      <Plot 
        data={plot.data} 
        layout={plot.layout} 
        config={{displaylogo: false}}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Bar
```

However, when I change the server-side code from Flask -> FastAPI, the webpage cease to show any graph. I can see the data successfully fetched from the FastAPI server by checking with console.log(plot) and post request status code is 200, but the graph is not shown on the webpage to some reason.

## **Server side: FastAPI**

```
@router.post("/bar")
async def bar():
    df = px.data.medals_wide()
    fig3 = px.bar(df, x="nation", y=["gold", "silver", "bronze"], title="Wide-Form Input", width=1000, height=650)
    graphJSON = plotly.io.to_json(fig3, pretty=True)
    return graphJSON
```

## **ReactJS**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Plot from 'react-plotly.js';
import './Bar.css'
import { getServerAddress } from '../../Constants';
import { getAccessToken } from '../../AccessToken';

function Bar() {
  const [plot, setPlot] = useState(0);
  console.log(getAccessToken())

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(getServerAddress() + "/api/v1/bar", {
      method: 'POST', 
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Basic " + getAccessToken(),
      }, 
      credentials: 'include',
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {setPlot(data);}); console.log(plot)}
  ,[]);

  return (
    <div className="bar">
      <Plot data={plot.data} layout={plot.layout} config={{displaylogo: false}}/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Bar
```

## ServerSide: main.py file

```
from typing import Union
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, HTTPException, Cookie, Request
# from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from starlette.middleware import Middleware
from starlette.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
import ldap
from time import sleep

from database import engine, get_database_session
import classes.database_schema as database_schema
from auth import createAccessToken, createRefreshToken, decodeRefreshToken

#from routers import admin
from routers import data_visualiztion

from classes.request_bodies import LoginPostBody
from classes.database_schema import User

def connectionAttempt():
    try:
        database_schema.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
        return 0
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return 1

while connectionAttempt() != 0:
    print("Error connecting to database. Will try again in 5 seconds...")
    sleep(5)

origins = [
    "http://localhost",
    "http://localhost:3000",
]

middleware = [
    Middleware(
        CORSMiddleware,
        allow_origins=origins,
        allow_credentials=True,
        allow_methods=["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"],
        allow_headers=['*']
    )
]

app = FastAPI(middleware=middleware)
#app.include_router(admin.router)
app.include_router(data_visualiztion.router)
```

After I replaced the Flask with FastAPI, I expected the same behavior - to display the graph on the webpage and the graph information is fetched from server. However, their code are almost the same, but only FLASK works and FastAPI version do not. Even FastAPI version don't work, there is no error, and data is successfully fetched. It's really weird.